# How to customize the docker image name in VS2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

In vs2019, I generate the docker image in the output window, the original command to generate the image was：

`docker build -f "e:\work\dotnetcoreproject\rookie.qwt\rookie.qwt.webapi\dockerfile" --force-rm -t rookieqwtwebapi  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=rookie.Qwt.WebApi" "e:\work\dotnetcoreproject\rookie.qwt"`

I want to change the image name `rookieqwtwebapi` to `registry.rookie.qwt.webapi`, how can I do it in vs2019?

Comment: Is that a command you wrote yourself, or is this something generated by Visual Studio? i.e. you don't just want to know how to change the command, you want to know where to configure VS to change the command it's generating?

Comment: I doubt what you are trying to do has anything to do with VS.

Answer (score 34):

> I want to change the image name rookieqwtwebapi to registry.rookie.qwt.webapi, how can I do it in vs2019?

According to the [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019), there's a parameter of `DockerfileTag` for this purpose:

> *The tag that will be used when building the Docker image. In debugging, a ":dev" is appended to the tag.*

So do it as below:

1. Double click your project name in Solution Explorer
2. Edit the project file, add a custom `<DockerfileTag/>`:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>65be249c-09e1-45ea-bac9-45d1cb4c82b6</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileTag>registry.rookie.qwt.webapi</DockerfileTag>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Now VS will build the image with this tag of `registry.rookie.qwt.webapi` (or `registry.rookie.qwt.webapi:dev` when debugging) automatically .

Comment: Good find.  And a Release build yields the _latest_ tag.  Not obvious the _DevicefileTag_ property affects the repo name.

Comment: You can also use <DockerfileBuildArguments>-t registry.rookie.qwt.webapi</DockerfileBuildArguments> to generate an image with a custom name.

Comment: I tried to use DockerfileTag but it seems is not changing my image name in the Azure Container Registry. It works fine locally and if I debug my application I see the correct image name in my local docker, but when publish on azure it continues to use the default name...any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Go to the *Properties* of the project and change the *Assembly* name. 
It will change the entire image name. Image tag can be added in *Publish Profile*.

Answer (score -2):

Use the `--tag` or `-t` shorthand to add a custom name for docker image. You can also add the tag with the image name. More info here - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Run this command to see the image name:

```
docker build -t registry.rookie.qwt.webapi -f "e:\work\dotnetcoreproject\rookie.qwt\rookie.qwt.webapi\dockerfile" --force-rm   --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=rookie.Qwt.WebApi" "e:\work\dotnetcoreproject\rookie.qwt"
```

Comment: thanks,i know the docker build  command ,but i want to know how to config  docker build command in vs2019

Comment: I don't understand the relation between docker command and visual studio. You can either execute the docker command using .Net CLI or use the docker-compose.yml file for it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and makes the most sense. You shouldn't have to change the assembly name constantly for creating different images as the other people had recommended. What if I want a {projectname}-debug {projectname}-testing version? This works perfectly, thanks.